# Present users with form to create new node

Tags: nodes

I have created a content type called "member" in my project. Logged in Users have permissions to create nodes of type "member".

I want to my users to be able to create the nodes without having to click "create member"

I simply want to present them with the form when they log in and all they have to do is 1. Enter the values and 2. Click save.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the user upon login to the create form. A good module for this (and a lot of other stuff) is: [logintoboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can create a page of node form as well as you can edit the page with user wise permission,

```
function yourmodule_changes_menu() {    
  $items = array();
  $items['member_page'] = array(
    'title' => 'Create member',
    'page callback' => 'yourmodule_member_page',    
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'),
    'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
  );  

  $items['member_page/edit/%node'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit member',
    'page callback' => 'yourmodule_member_page',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access callback' => 'member_node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('update', 2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'),
    'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
  );
  return $items;
}

function member_node_access($op, $node, $account = NULL) {
    $rights = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
    if((!$node) || ($op != "update")){
        return FALSE;
    }
    // If no user object is supplied, the access check is for the current user.
    if (empty($account)) {
        $account = $GLOBALS['user'];
    }

    $can_user_edit = node_access('update', $node, $account);
    if(($can_user_edit) || ($node->uid == $account->uid)){
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

function yourmodule_member_page($node = NULL) {  
  global $user;
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

  if ($node && $node->nid) {
    // Load the node edit form
    drupal_set_title(check_plain($node->title));
    $form = drupal_get_form('member_node_form', $node);
  }
  else {
    // Create new blog post
    $node = (object) array(
      'uid' => $user->uid,
      'name' => $user->name,
      'type' => 'member',      
      'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
    );
    $form = drupal_get_form('member_node_form', $node);

      $variables['element'] = $form;

      // here render your content type fields 
      $output  = drupal_render($form['title']);  
      $output .= drupal_render($form['body']); 
      $output .= drupal_render($form['field_category']);
      $output .= drupal_render($form['actions']);
      $variables['element']['#children'] = $output;
  }

  return theme_form($variables);
}
```

To redirect user to member page after login, there are many ways:

```
using [logintoboggan][1] or 
using rule module or 
using hook_user_login function
```